# First letter of the string in C

Tags: c, string, printf

I want to print the first letter of a string, but I get a runtime error.

This is my code:

```
int main(void) {

    char str[] = "Hello";
    printf("%s\n", str[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not shure if this is how strings work in C, so if you have some advice please help.

Comment: In printf use `%c` for single char, `%s` is for strings.

Comment: @jpw - thank you! You saved me from some great horror :D !

Comment: You commented below you are using on-line compilers.  Why not download complete MinGW C/C++ compiler.  Its freely available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A C-string is a series of characters that is terminated by a 0 byte, otherwise known as a null terminated string. It can be accessed either as an array ( char[ ] ) or as a pointer to the first character ( char * ).** 
Note: Array always begain from 0 index position.

Here in your code `str` string is something like:

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

> str[0] = 'H' 
>   str[1] = 'e' 
>   str[2] = 'l' 
>   str[3] = 'l' 
>   str[4] = 'o' 
>   str[5] = '\0'

so, you can print any char of that string by simply using `printf`

```
    printf( "%c",str[0] ); // for the first, changing the value if number you can change the position of character to be printed
```

you have used `%s` which is used to print a whole string

```
   printf( "%s",str );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `%c` to print single character

```
   printf("%c \n", str[0]);
```

to print entire string you need to use %s

```
   printf("%s\n", str);
```

you would get a `warning` with your code, so heed to warnings

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wf
ormat=]                                                                                                  
     printf("%s\n", str[0]);
```

Comment: Rajesh - ty for the info. Sadly, I used an online compiler that gave me nothing except a normal runtime error :( !

Comment: try out https://www.sourcelair.com, it has nice linux console interface. it is not a promotion, i use it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `"%c"` option to print single character with `printf`, `"%s"` is for strings. You will get segmentation fault in your example. Compile your program with

```
gcc -Os -Wall -pedantic main.c &&  ./a.out
```

to issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++ & reject all programs that use forbidden extensions. This will produce a warning:

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2
>   has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
>        printf("%s\n", str[0]);

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a56055e381c209f1

Answer (score 0):

This might help to get your results expected:

```
int main(void) {

/*changed from str[] to *str 
*/

char *str = "Hello";

/*changed from %s to %c
*/

printf("%c\n", str);

return 0;
```

}

This will print the first variable of char length pointed to by str.